# Implement Validation Where Textbox Gets Red Highlight On Failure

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

How does one make a textbox highlighted with red color when an event occurred like invalid number format in c#?

Comment: like invalid username, invalid password etc..

Comment: You can do either client side (through JavaScript) or do it after server validation (either with a full post-back or via AJAX).  How you do it depends on which route you want to use.

Comment: @Tim - the question is tagged `winforms`, unlikely to be using JavaScript in this case.

Comment: sorry i want it in c#, have to highlight text box when user enters other then number

Comment: @ChrisF - yeah, I saw that after my comment.  Silly me for not looking at the tags :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not terribly clear what you mean, but it *sounds* like you want to do something like:

- Hook up an event handler for whenever the text changes in a textbox
- In that event handler, check whether the text can be parsed as a number, ideally using `int.TryParse` (rather than just parsing it and catching an exception)
- Setting the foreground colour of the textbox to red or black, depending on whether the parsing attempt was successful

So something like:

```
textBox.TextChanged += (sender, args) => {
    int ignored;
    bool valid = int.tryParse(textBox.Text, out ignored);
    textBox.ForeColor = valid ? Color.Black : Color.Red;
};
```

(There may well be other rather more sophisticated ways of doinig this, including preventing the invalid input to start with... but for *just* changing the colour, this will work :)

Comment: and one more thing, if i press tab i mean leaving that textbox it should only leave that control if it is correct formatted... any help please..

Comment: @Chandran: You can use an event around losing focus to catch tabbing away. I don't know about the border though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the errorProvider. You can highligth the input or blink it, etc.

Take a look a this post in order to try it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx#Y2680

Answer (score 1):

Just adjust the property `ForeColor` of the control displaying the text based on the result of your validation, e.g. `label1.ForeColor = isInputValid ? Color.Black : Color.Red;` where `isInputValid` is a boolean value set wherever you do validation.

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear why Skeet uses the event `TextChanged` when there is a `Validating` event and a `Validated` event.

What you want is the `MaskedTextBox` which can work with your number

See [Overview of how to validate user input (Windows Forms .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/validation?view=netdesktop-5.0) and within that document [Event-driven validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/validation?view=netdesktop-5.0#event-driven-validation).